# Xero - OAuth1 to OAuth2 migration

Tags: xero-api

I started working with adding migration from OAuth1a to OAuth2 inside my application and i face some problems.

This is what I've done :

1. I updated my partner app just like it is described here https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/migrate (added Auth2.0 redirect , got client id and secret etc ...)
2. I implemented token migration exactly as it is done here https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-net-oauth2-sampletokenmigration and it works fine when OAuth1 token is valid :)

But when it is invalid and I'm doing refresh (using app updated in step 1) and call ~/oauth/migrate endpoint (using access token that i just recived after refresh step) to get OAuth2  token. I'm reciving  this error "You can only migrate an OAuth1.0a connection to an OAuth2.0 connection for the currently authorised app". Also same thing  happen when i create new connection  (using partner applications  created in in step 1) and than try to migrate this access token to Auth2.0.

Can anybody point me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the error returned when you try to migrate to a **newly** created app. Are you sure you are using the tokens from the same **Partner** app tile in your /myapps dashboard.

It should look something like this, once you've added the correct OAuth2 redirect uri and generated your secret.

[image: example partner upgrade]

Comment: hi @SerKnight, could you please advise is it necessary to refresh existing Xero oauth 1.0 token before migrate it to oauth 2.0 ?

Comment: Yes you have to freshly migrate the tokens prior to migrating. Here is blog and webinar recording that I encourage you watch prior - https://devblog.xero.com/xeroapi-oauth-migration-strategy-8af06389ba32 & https://xero.zoom.us/rec/play/kpQSwOyKjafYpmKwRmQNpTD1eUhL5woEry7_mS_hYe_DesAtAch-H8mAYjXDaKlAiab34TZ6wH5ln1Kd.ACYqaEuRnQ23xs8K?autoplay=true&startTime=1595436900000